# Посоветуйте хороший учебник по C++ в Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Нужен хороший учебник по программированию на C++ в Qt Creator, а лучше несколько разного уровня: от просто написанного объясняющего базовые вещи, до более сложного продвинутого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Макс Шлее – "Qt 5.10 Профессиональное программирование на C++".
Плюс есть хорошие ресурсы [здесь](http://qt-doc.ru/) и, конечно же, [официальная документация](https://doc.qt.io/) для тех, кто хоть немного знаком с английским и умеет пользоваться переводчиками

Comment: Книга хорошая, но не думаю что выкладывание пиратских ссылок на форуме - это хорошая идея

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Я на форуме недавно, спасибо за подсказку, поправил.